# How to use elements in two columns from a DataFrame as a dictionary to be applied in another DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, python-re

So, I have data from a wildlife rehabilitation center, and each animal received enters the database with it's common name and a unique ID number.

I have to take all these common names and write the respective scientific name of the species.

So, my plan was to use the official species list of my country, which is available as an Excel file, as a dictionary to be applied in my original DataFrame of animals received.

However, the official species list comes with several common names for each species.

Here I have a exemple on how my original DataFrame is configurated, with IDnumber and common name, and bellow two exemples of official lists of mammal and birds, with scientifc name and common name

```
my_list = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[300,301,302,303,304,305] ,'Common_name':['North American opossum','Cougar','Virginia opossum','Common pigeon','Black vulture','Elk']})

mammal_list = pd.DataFrame({'Species':['Didelphis virginiana','Ursus arctos','Puma concolor'],'Common_name':['North American opossum, Virginia opossum','Brown bear, Grizzly bears','North American cougar, Cougar, Puma, Mountain lion']})

birds_list = pd.DataFrame({'Species':['Anser caerulescens','Columba livia','Coragyps atratus'],'Common_name':['Snow goose,Blue goose','Rock dove, Rock pigeon, Common pigeon','Black vulture, American black vulture, Mexican vulture']})
```

I want to use both official lists as dictionary for my_list, but the correspondece would be created only if the value for common name in my list of animals was the same as all the values in the official list.

So, how can I create a dictionary that understands that each species has a list of possible common names, use it in my list's "common_name" column, and search for a match with any value in a list of possible values for each row in the official list and then create a new column in my list with the scientific name

What I'm aiming for is a dic that can creat a new 'Species' column, taking my_list 'Common_name', creating thus something like

```
my_list = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[300,301,302,303,304,305] ,'Common_name':['North American opossum','Cougar','Virginia opossum','Common pigeon','Black vulture','Elk'], 'Species':['Didelphis virginiana','Puma concolor', 'Didelphis virginiana','Columba livia','Coragyps atratus', <NA>]})
```

First I tried to create a dictionary with the official_list's columns and apply to my list

```
dic = dict(zip(birds_list['Common_name'], birds_list['Species']))
```

```
my_list['spp'] = my_list['Common_name'].map(dic)
```

This of course returned no match, as in my list there's only one common name for each ID number (sometimes the same species is registered with different common names as well, specially birds)

Then I tried to separate each name, by using regular expressions, as each common name in a single row is separeted by a ","

```
regex = re.compile(r"(\,)")
birds_list['Common_name'].str.findall(regex)
birds_list['Common_name'].str.extract(regex)
```

Then I tried to create a column with just the first common name caputured, but this list has tons of NA for some reason

```
birds_list['common_name'] = birds_list['Common_name'].str.extract(regex)[0]
```

So I'm really stuck here, by now I really thinking of doing this manually, but I have 7.000 animal per year for a 5 years spam

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to split the `Common_name` column then `.explode`

```
>>> birds_list
              Species                                        Common_name
0  Anser caerulescens                              Snow goose,Blue goose
1       Columba livia              Rock dove, Rock pigeon, Common pigeon
2    Coragyps atratus  Black vulture, American black vulture, Mexican...
```

```
birds_list.assign(Common_name = 
   birds_list["Common_name"].str.split(r"\s*,\s*")
).explode("Common_name")
```

```
              Species             Common_name
0  Anser caerulescens              Snow goose
0  Anser caerulescens              Blue goose
1       Columba livia               Rock dove
1       Columba livia             Rock pigeon
1       Columba livia           Common pigeon
2    Coragyps atratus           Black vulture
2    Coragyps atratus  American black vulture
2    Coragyps atratus         Mexican vulture
```

You can then build your `common_name -> species` mapping.